# Releases for the Lord of the Rings LCG

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

I have been thinking of getting into the Lord of the Rings LCG from Fantasy Flight Games. I realize the game has been out for a while and there are a LOT of deluxe expansions and Adventure Packs for the game.

Does anyone know the release order for the Expansions and Packs and the general theme of each?

That would probably help me in deciding what I want/need to pick up first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *two ways* you can go about collecting the [expansions](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=129&esem=2), one is **order of release**, the second is **chronological order of events**.

Here are a couple good resources for choosing what order to buy the expansions in:

### [New Player Buying Guide (Updated January 2015)](https://talesfromthecards.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/new-player-buying-guide/)

This guy went through the effort of placing each expansion into chronological order of events according to the books, I've quoted his summary below.

### [Play Chronology / Quests Timeline](http://community.fantasyflightgames.com/index.php?/topic/75663-play-chronology-quests-timeline/?p=734609)

> ## To Summarize…
>
> ### The Quests in Chronological Order
>
> **Over the Hill and Under Hill** (2941 TA) [Gadalf: Sending an Hobbit to
>   slay the last fire breathing dragon. What could possibly go wrong? On
>   a totally unrelated sidenote, dang these are some good pipeweed!]
>
> **Battle at Laketown** (2941 TA) [Bard: Stupid Dwarves, stupid fat Hobbit,
>   and most of all stupid procrastinating weed addict wizard. In the end
>   I did all the work and all saving laketown and all slaying Smaug.]
>
> **Shadow of Mirkwood** (3009 ~ 3017 TA) [Gandalf: Oh, Sauron is in action
>   again? Ah oh… he must be searching for the One Ring….. I am kind of
>   suspicious about Bilbo's ring. Maybe I will try and learn more about
>   Bilbo's ring by questioning Gollum]
>
> **Core Set** (Spring/Summer 3009 TA) [Thranduil: Oh shizzle, the fortress
>   of Dol Guldur, which White Council cleansed couple decades ago, is
>   sending out evil vibes again. I better send warning to all nearby
>   allies]
>
> **Khazad-Dum** (3009 TA Early Winter) [Elrond: I'm hearing a lot of
>   reports about evil things stirring in the Misty Mountains and Mirkwood
>   and such. But oddly no report came from Moria for… 15 years, that
>   seems like a long time. Maybe I'll send someone to check them out, to
>   see if they are doing okay.]
>
> **Dwarrowdelf** (3009 TA Winter) [Elrond: Sweety how was your journey over
>   the Mountain? I know it was wintertime but Lorien was just too close
>   to Dol Guldur. What? You were attacked by the Orcs? Come to think of
>   it, the scouts I've sent to Moria hasn't returned yet. This is
>   concerning… maybe I'll send another group to see Moria has something
>   to do with increased Orc activity.
>
> **Massing at Osgiliath / Heirs of Numenor** (3019 TA) [Sauron: I will
>   launch multiple attacks against Gondor on various fronts to see how
>   strong their defences are. Also, while they are busy defending my
>   'attacks', I will sneak my Nazguls disguised as 'Black Riders' across
>   the river Anduin in search for this Shire, Baggins to get my Ring
>   back.]

Answer (score 1):

Most of the information you are looking for can be found directly in Fantasy Flight's store.

http://store.fantasyflightgames.com/showproducts.cfm?FullCat=248

There's a list of all the expansions, and each expansion has a description of its theme. I'm not sure of a simple way to find the release order.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider even looking at the Saga Expansions. They condense the thematic elements of the novels, telling the story in a more condensed version versus spreading it apart across a bunch of adventure packs. The additional benefit here is that the Saga Expansions do not require adventure packs much like the deluxe expansions do.

And...as they come available, you could outfit your collection with reprints of older adventure packs and deluxe expansions as you see fit.